# Making an installer

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

i have tried every guide possible but i just cant seem to make an installer for my application.

I keep getting errors / warning about my dll files (ieframe.dll and another custom chemistry control) which says `the following files may have dependencies that cannot be determined automatically. Please confirm all dependencies have been added to the project`

I have no idea what to do, every dll file under references in my main project is set to `copy if newer` and all the dll files appear in my installed folder when i run the installer.

does anyone know how to fix this.

Thanks

edit: when i run the installer i get an error with the dll saying

`Module C:\....... .dll failed to register.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error, it is a warning. Is is hard (if not impossible) for Visual Studio to find out if all dependencies of a COM dll are taken care of by the installer. This is why Visual Studio is warning you to have a look.

This is not something to fix.

**EDIT after adding more to the question**

The message you are getting **might** be related to the warning but it doesn't have to be.

If it is a COM DLL (and I suppose it is because those need to be registered) it might depend on another dll that should be present before being able to register it. It is also possible that another prerequisite is not met; e.g., a specific OS version.

Did you check the eventlog for more information? Can you tell us the actual name of the dll? I noticed this message also when trying to register a 64 bit dll on a 32-bit OS but there can be many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some external Application\s like Smart Install Maker or Install Shield